# get_reader() got multiple values for argument 'mode'

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
   reader = read(uri, format,"i", **kwargs)
    with reader:
        return reader.get_data(0)
```

I m getting error in above mentioned lines. I m not able to find error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What context are you in? What are you trying to do? What programming language is this?

Comment: it is python programming language. i m trying to do image to image translation using cycle GAN.

Comment: i m trying to reproduce results of this github repository. https://github.com/H2K804/CycleGAN-medical-image-segmentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reader = read(uri, format,"i", **kwargs)

I expect the "i" parameter is the mode argument (though I gues it could also be `format`), but the kwargs dict also contains a value for mode. As a result, Python gets a conflict where the mode argument is provided twice, and reports an error.

Either fix your positional parameters, or fix your kwargs, or update your kwarg with a default mode using `kwargs.setdefault('mode', 'i')` (that way `mode` is set to `'i'` when it was missing, but if it's already present it doesn't get replaced).

edit: opening an issue on their repository because your completely unrelated code is broken or nonsensical is not cool